# Why does Java's Date.getYear() return 111 instead of 2011?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am having a bit of trouble parsing a string date to a `Date` object. I use a `DateFormat` to parse the string, and when I print the value of the date, it gives me what I expect.

But when I try get the day, the month or the year it gives me the wrong values. For instance, the year is 2011, but when I do `.getYear()` it gives me 111. I have no idea why this is happening. Here is the relevant code segment:

```
    Date dateFrom = null;

    String gDFString = g.getDateFrom();

    System.out.println(gDFString);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try {
        dateFrom = df.parse("04/12/2011");

        System.out.println(dateFrom);

        System.out.println(dateFrom.getYear());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I out print `dateFrom`, I get `Sun Dec 04 00:00:00 GMT 2011`, which is what you would expect. But printing `.getYear()` returns `111`.

I need to be able to get the day, month and year of the date for a time series graph.

Comment: It hasn’t even *once* occured to you to read the documentation of [Date.getYear()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear(%29) which clearly states that it returns “the year represented by this date, minus 1900“?

Comment: Many programmers (including me) would expect year 2011 to be parsed as 2011, not 2011 - 1900 for sure. i think it's Java's implementation which is weird (no matter what internal reasons are behind it), not the OP.

Answer (score 46):

Those methods have been *deprecated*. Instead, use the [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

---

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public final class DateParseDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         try {
             c.setTime(df.parse("04/12/2011"));
             System.out.println("Year = " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
             System.out.println("Month = " + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
             System.out.println("Day = " + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
         } 
         catch (ParseException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Year = 2011
Month = 3
Day = 12
```

---

And as for the *month* field, this is 0-based. This means that January = 0 and December = 11. As stated by the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH),

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars is `JANUARY` which is `0`; the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year.

Comment: Not just you, @Ich

Comment: I dont know why they do 0 - Jan 11- Dec.. need to do several ugly step just to change the month position to match the index..

Comment: @Ich Yes, the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are an awful mess. That is why they are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 12):

[Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to the rescue:

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.
>
> Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the
>   year that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by
>   this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

You should not use deprecated methods. Deprecated methods are methods which should not be used anymore. But whatever the method you're using, read its javadoc to know what it does.

Answer (score 9):

President Evil nailed it, `Date.getYear()` returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains. And you you shouldn't use it.

But quick fix for the code in the question is:

```
Date dateFrom = null;

String gDFString = g.getDateFrom();

System.out.println(gDFString);

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

try {
    dateFrom = df.parse("04/12/2011");

    System.out.println(dateFrom);

    // Add 1900 to dateFrom.getYear() 

    System.out.println(dateFrom.getYear()+1900);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29

The specification states that it returns the year minus 1900.  Probably a good idea to avoid deprecated methods as well.

Comment: I used '(value.getYear()+1900)', and worked great, thanks for tte tip of years from 1900.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
int year = 
    LocalDate.parse( 
        "04/12/2011" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.US ) 
    ).getYear() ;
```

> 2011

## java.time

The troublesome `java.util.Date` class and its siblings are now supplanted by the excellent java.time classes.

```
String input = "04/12/2011";
Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

The java.time classes utilize sane numbering, with:

- Months 1-12 for January-December
- 2011 means 2011
- Days of week are 1-7 for Monday-Sunday (per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)).

Interrogate the `LocalDate` for its constituent parts.

```
int year = ld.getYear();  // 2011
int month = ld.getMonthValue();  // 4
int dayOfMonth = ld.getDayOfMonth();  // 12
```

You can even ask for automatically localized name of month and name of day-of-week.

```
String monthName = ld.getMonth().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , Locale.CANDA_FRENCH ); // avril
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a guess, but the 111 could be the number of years since 1900. Take a look at documentation/do some tests to verify this (I can't check at the moment)