# Can't get the real date from a Date object i java

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Java’s Date.getYear()  return 111 instead of 2011?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215621/why-does-javas-date-getyear-return-111-instead-of-2011)

I am trying to get the year, month and day form a Date-object, but the following gives me something completely random:

```
    Date d = new Date();
    System.out.println(d.getYear() + " - " + d.getMonth() + " - " + d.getDay());
```

I get: 112 - 9 - 1

Does anyone know why? And do you have a bette apporch? For my program i need the Date objects.

Comment: Opposite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021060/java-date-output-is-wrong-why

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) of these three methods (which are deprecated and thus shouldn't be used, BTW) would tell you why:

- 112 : number of years since 1900
- 9: month number, starting from 0 (so 9 means october)
- 1: day of month

Use a Calendar to get date fields, and a DateFormat to format dates.

Comment: Precisely what I was gonna post +1

Comment: I think last one must be DAY_OF_WEEK. not day of month

Answer (score 1):

Yup... the [docs know](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Specifically, the year that `getYear` returns is the current Gregorian year minus 1900.

Further still, those getters are deprecated. You should use the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

If you *must* take Date objects in, then use `Calendar.getInstance().setTime(dateObject)`

Answer (score 1):

Source code explains the reason.

```
@Deprecated
public int getYear() {
    return normalize().getYear() - 1900;
}
@Deprecated
public int getMonth() {
return normalize().getMonth() - 1; // adjust 1-based to 0-based
}

@Deprecated
public int getDay() {
return normalize().getDayOfWeek() - gcal.SUNDAY;
}
```