# Java Date output is wrong. Why?

Tags: java, date

I'am playing with Java Date and can't understand this:

```
Date myBirth = new Date(1991,01,21);
Log.d("DATE: ", "" + myBirth);
```

Here I initialized Date object. Why I get this output?

```
DEBUG/DATE:(31693): Sat Feb 21 00:00:00 EET 3891
```

Comment: January is month 0, February is month 1.

Comment: You may wish to avoid writing numeric literals with a leading 0. A leading 0 tells Java to interpret the number as an octal. For numbers less than 8 this makes no difference. However 010 == 8.

Comment: this constructor is deprecated. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661723/how-do-i-set-custom-date-in-android

Comment: Opposite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020507/cant-get-the-real-date-from-a-date-object-i-java

Answer (score 3):

From the [Date docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> - A year y is represented by the integer y - 1900.
> - A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is  February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.

Comment: @AlexKulakovsky, did you read the rest of that document?  Specifically the bit that say you pass in the number of years since 1900?

Comment: Oops, left the year part out of my original answer, updated now.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) of this **deprecated** constructor of Date:

```
Parameters:
    year - the year **minus 1900**.
    month - the month between 0-11.
    date - the day of the month between 1-31.
```

So the output is what you ask, but not what you want.