# Regarding current month and year in Android Application

Tags: java, android, date

In Android Application, I am trying to retrieve the current month and year, by using the following code.

```
setMonth(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMonth());
setYear(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getYear());
System.out.println("MONTH sssssssssss:" + Month);
System.out.println("YEAR ssssssssssss:" +  Year);
```

output is

```
04-20 16:36:43.723: I/System.out(4718): MONTH sssssssssss:3
04-20 16:36:43.723: I/System.out(4718): YEAR ssssssssssss:114
```

Could someone please help me to correct year value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following instead

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
int month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH); // january == 0 btw
int year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
// do your printing here
```

The reason you are getting `114` is because the `getTime()` method returns a `java.util.Date` class, and by default, the `java.util.Date` class has its year value offset by 1900 (don't ask me why). This means that the current year would be `2014` - `1900` = `114`, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Here is a related SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215621/why-does-javas-date-getyear-return-111-instead-of-2011