# SimpleDateFormat. format returning wrong date

Tags: java, date, format, simpledateformat

I have this code I would like to know why it returns correct date

```
Festival f= (Festival) festival.get(0);
Date d=f.getSDate();


System.out.println(d.getYear());
System.out.println(d.getMonth());
System.out.println(d.getDate());


SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // define your format.
String formattedDate = df.format(d);
System.out.println("New Date To Show::"+formattedDate);
```

the output is this

```
2019
2
27
New Date To Show::27/03/3919
```

Comment: a formatter doesn't set a date, it merely shows the one you already have in another way. My first recommendation: don't use the Date class anymore, there are far better.

Comment: It's because the month (d.getMonth()) starts from zero and 2 is actually 3

Comment: I [cannot reproduce your problem](https://rextester.com/GYAH95097).  Please post a reproducible issue.

Comment: Months are `0` based in the `Date` class, and years are `1900` based. You seem to be creating the date incorrectly.

Comment: can you post getSDate() in Festival class ?

Comment: As already stated: the month is 0 based, so both your outputs are correct. But the classes you use are deprecated, so you should switch to new alternatives instead:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMonth--

Comment: side note: not use Date is outdated instead use new `java time api`

Comment: A good article to check the java.time api https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: Related (only opposite): [Why does Java's Date.getYear() return 111 instead of 2011?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215621/why-does-javas-date-getyear-return-111-instead-of-2011)

Comment: Not only is the `Date` class long outdated, the `getXx` methods are officially deprecated. Don’t use `Date`, and even if you do, *certainly* avoid the deprecated methods. Additionally it seems you’ve got a day in the wrong year from `f.getSDate()`. I recommend you use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time and forget about `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. I promise, it will clear all confusion.

Comment: Thanks, @VinodSinghBist, for the good link. Ahmed, if you haven’t given up on `Date` by now, here’s a good blogpost on that class: [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this :

```
   Date date=new Date(); 
   // you can assign your return from the function here



    LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    System.out.println(localDate.getMonthValue());
    System.out.println(localDate.getDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println(localDate.getYear());


    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String formattedDate = df.format(date);
    System.out.println("New Date To Show::"+formattedDate);
```

Comment: Further details at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182996/java-get-month-integer-from-date

Comment: On one hand it doesn’t solve the problem of `f.getSDate()` returning a date in year 3919. On the other hand we haven’t got any information that may help us help the asker solve the mentioned problem (except by changing the method’s return type to `LocalDate`). I’d additionally take the step and format the `LocalDate` using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: f.getSDate() returns a Date type object ( as per the question shows). you can replace the same on the code I shared and carry on with the required operations.

Comment: it still returns the year 3919 and changes the month value. :(

Comment: It *must* change the  month value (otherwise it would be an error). March is 2 in `Date` and 3 in `LocalDate`, so it’s changed from 2 to 3. Your problem is you’re getting the wrong `Date` from `f.getSDate()`. @Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

It's because the month (d.getMonth()) starts from zero and 2 is actually 3