# Parse Date String Return Wrong Month

Tags: java, android, date, localdate, threetenbp

I try to parse date string but always get wrong month. Here's my code.

This is code to select date from calender

```
@OnClick(R.id.tedit_tgllahir_addnew) void showTimeDialog(){
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        date = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddDataForNewUserActivity.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        etTgl.setText(String.format("%02d/%02d/%02d", year, month+1, dayOfMonth));
                    }

                }, year, month, date);

        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

and this is when i want to parse data

```
birth = LocalDate.of(list.getTglLahirAnak().getYear() + 1900, list.getTglLahirAnak().getMonth(), list.getTglLahirAnak().getDate());
                        int year =  Period.between(birth, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
                        int month = Period.between(birth, LocalDate.now()).getMonths();
                        int totalBulan = year * 12 + month;
```

Whenever I input date from the calender, it always shows the wrong month. For example I choose May but in the system read April. Thanks to all who are willing to help.

Comment: I recommend you neither use `Calendar` nor `Date`. Both classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Just stay with `LocalDate` and `Period` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate). The comments under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26597701/5772882) are relevant when using ThreeTenABP.

Comment: I wrote a quick [new answer for you here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63068341/5772882).

Comment: As an aside it seems that you can use [`Period.toTotalMonths()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#toTotalMonths()) to your advantage.

Comment: Or does this answer your question? [SimpleDateFormat. format returning wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395261/simpledateformat-format-returning-wrong-date)

Answer (score 1):

I gather from your question that you are using the backport of JSR-310, probably the Android edition, ThreeTenABP. If so, go all-in on that and drop the use of the poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar` and `Date` classes.

Even if the use of the `Date` class is dictated from outside of your control, you must still stay away from its deprecated methods including `getYear()`, `getMonth()` and `getDate()`. You are trying the good thing when receiving a `Date` and converting it to a `LocalDate` first thing. Use `DateTimeUtils` from the backport for a first conversion.

But let’s take it from the top. Use `LocalDate` for setting the initial date of your date picker. Don’t use the old-fashioned `Calendar` class. I have not compiled the code, so please forgive if there’s a typo.

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    year = today.getYear();
    month = today.getMonthValue(); // naturally 1-based
    date = today.getDayOfMonth();
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddDataForNewUserActivity.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // will return to this part later
                }

            }, year, month - 1, date); // Pass 0-based month
```

When the user selects a date from the calendar/date picker, don’t store it as a string. Store it as a `LocalDate` object. This saves you from doing any parsing later, and your code also shows that you need a `LocalDate`. Obviously if you want to show the selected date to the user, format the date into a string for that purpose (only). Use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy/MM/dd");
```

Now we go:

```
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // Store the selected date somewhere you can find it later
                    selectedLocalDate = LocalDate.of(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
                    // Display to the user
                    String formattedDate = selectedLocalDate.format(dateFormatter);
                    etTgl.setText(formattedDate);
                }
```

Now the calculation of age in months poses no problem anymore:

```
    birth = selectedLocalDate;
    long totalBulan = Period.between(birth, LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
                           .toTotalMonths();
```

If you cannot control what you get from `list.getTglLahirAnak()`, the conversion from `Date` to `LocalDate` is:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = list.getTglLahirAnak();
    birth = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(oldfashionedDate)
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDate();
```

Now the calculation of age proceeds as before.

### What went wrong in your code?

Just like the outdated `Calendar` also the deprecated `Date.getMonth()` numbers the months from 0 for January through 11 for December. So if you pick a date in May, `list.getTglLahirAnak().getMonth()` returns 4 for May. When you feed this into a `LocalDate` with its natural and sensible month numbering, it gives you April.